# Does starting a new single-player game reset my Online character?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've been wanting to start a new GTA 5 single-player game, but don't want my Online character to reset. Will my character be reset if I start a new game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters are entirely separate. Restarting one doesn't affect the other.

My own knowledge but also mentioned on [Rockstar forums](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200777178-If-i-start-story-mode-over-on-GTA-5-will-my-online-character-disapear-) years ago.